# Array and override (no global array)

Tags: php

How i can override the table in other classes, and display it in the first And with three fields?

```
<?php 

class A {  
  public $tab = array();

  public function wyswietl() { 
    $this->tab['id'] = '1';
    foreach ($this->tab as $key => $value) {
      print $key .' = '. $value;
    }
  }
}

class B {
  public function dodajB() {
    $this->tab['desc'] = 'descriptions'; 
  }
}

class C
{
  public function dodajC() {
    $this->tab['name'] = 'names'; 
  }
}

$ob = new A;

$ob2 = new B;
$ob2->dodajB();

$ob3 = new C;
$ob3->dodajC();

$ob->wyswietl();

?>
```

Comment: Please improve your question so that we have a clear understanding of what you are asking. Until that time, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ob is defined as an object of class A.  To get all three columns you would need to make it of class C and have C extend from B which extends from A.  I would also recommend using the __construct function to construct your objects for you.  Also you were referencing a local variable of tab rather than the class one using this to reference it.

See the code below which does all of the above:

```
<?php 

class A
{  
   public $tab = array();

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->tab['id'] = '1';
   }

   public function wyswietl()
   { 
      foreach ($this->tab as $key => $value)
      {
          print $key .' = '. $value . "\n";
      }
   }
}

class B extends A
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->tab['desc'] = 'descriptions';
   }
}

class C extends B
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->tab['name'] = 'names'; 
   }
}

$ob = new A;

$ob2 = new B;
$ob3 = new C;

echo 'A: ';
$ob->wyswietl();
echo "\n\n";

echo 'B: ';
$ob2->wyswietl();
echo "\n\n";

echo 'C: ';
$ob3->wyswietl();
echo "\n\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're question is confusing, but I think you are looking for:

```
class B extends A {
    public function dodajB(){
        $this->tab['desc'] = 'descriptions'; 
    }
}

class C extends B {
    ...
```